# "I got worried... city, and I might not be able to get it back to the store and ask for a replacement."Is that sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Consider the following sentence:

> I got worried because the store was in another city, and I might not be able to get it back to the store and ask for a replacement.

My question is about this part: "I might not be able to get ..." is it the right tense or structure? Because I can use "I might not be able to " for present tense and present situation as well, but the speaker is talking about a past event, and in that period of time "he was not able to get back to .."

Comment: @Astralbee is right, you won't get an answer to your specific example. But to help you out with your general question about matching tenses, there's no rule that all tenses have to be the same (if that's what you mean by *in agreement*).  *This morning I went shopping, and now I am back home.*

Comment: @Astralbee This is true if there's no direct correlation between the two sentences. In example question, the person expresses his worries in the past, and again he expresses a pissibility of inability to get back to the store [in that past context] NOT [now]. I apprecaite your comments and help. Thank you.

Comment: @sharooz your edit shows some research and reasoning now - that's much better

Comment: Your sentence sounds perfectly idiomatic to my American English ear.  Although "got worried" indicates that you gradually became worried, which is possible, of course, but with a sentence in isolation about the difficulty of returning an item for replacement, there's no real context to support gradual worry.  You could say "I was worried".

Comment: More on the difference between "was worried" and "got worried".  With "got worried" there is usually a mention of something sudden that "triggers" the worry: *I got worried when the car started making weird noises* or *I got worried when you didn't come home on time.*.  When the cause of the worry is not sudden but was known all along, it would be more idiomatic to use "was worried". *When I let my son ride his bike to school alone for the first time, I was worried he would get hurt because drivers do not obey the speed limit and are rushing to work in the morning.*

Answer (score 2):

"I might not" is a *hypothetical*, so don't overthink the tense. In English we can use the past tense to make hypothetical statements about the past or future. For example, "*I might have broken my leg*" expresses concern over a past action, whereas "*I might have a drink*" expresses the possibility you might do something in the future.

Your example is a little confusing, but not unusual. It would be clearer if it read:

> I was worried **that**, because the store was in another city, I might not be able to get it back to the store and ask for a replacement.

As it stands, the speaker is describing what they *were* worried about *at the time* and may be how an English speaker might speak extemporaneously.

Answer (score 0):

> I got worried because the store was in another city, and I might not be able to get it back to the store and ask for a replacement.

It's not wrong to say **"I might not be able to"**. We say that to talk hypothetically about something in the present,past or future. We say that to express uncertainty when we’re not sure.

**Examples**:

> - I might not be able to visit you next Sunday.
> - I might not be able to pass the exam now because I haven't read enough.
> - I might not be able to sleep easy tonight.
> - I was under stress yesterday. I visited my mother to the hospital and I might not be able to finish my homework.

Comment: I think you're replying to a different question than asked. The OP wants to know whether the first "might not be able to" is correct (specifically about the tense agreement), not whether they need or not need a second one.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Hi! I believe that the OP wants to know why we write 'ask'. The sentence is in Simple Past and the OP wonders why we don't write 'asked'. Thank you very much for your opinion. I edited that question but the edit  is not visible to you yet.

Comment: Thank everyone, I asked if "I might not be able" is the write tense here or not? Because the narrater is talking about the past event!  I can use "I might not be able" in a present situation as well.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Hi! You are right! I didn't understand what the OP wanted to know. Thank you very much for your help. I edited again my answer . Do you like it now?

Comment: Personally, I would use _may not_ in all those examples (assuming the homework is still ongoing), but it's not wrong to use _might_ for an uncertainty in the present or future. The question was about _might_ in the past tense, though!

Comment: @KateBunting  Hi! Thank you very for your opinion and your help !I edited my answer again. Do you like it?

Comment: You misunderstood me. It is **always** right to use _might_  for an uncertainty in the past. _Might_ can also be used for talking about the present and future, but I personally prefer _may_.  (_Might_ is correct in the OP's sentence, because it's about someone's feelings in the past - _I got worried_.)

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou Thank you. I think I got the answer. Yes, my concern was about if "I might not be able to ..." a right choice in that setting, which you solved the problem, NO, it should've been "I couldn't".

Comment: @Shahrooz - There is **nothing wrong** with _might not_ in your sentence. The speaker was worried (in the past) because there was a risk that, if they needed a replacement after that time, they might not be able to get one.

Comment: @Shahrooz Hi! I edited again my answer. Additionally, I want to tell you that it's not wrong to say "I got worried because the store was in another city, and I could not  get it back to the store and ask for a replacement."

Comment: @Kate Bunting Hi! Thank you very much for your help!